# hit.IntersectionPoint returns NaNs in matlab's ButtonDownFcn

Tags: matlab-app-designer

I have developed a GUI with Matlab's AppDesigner. To pick up mouse clicks, I set the `ButtonDownFcn` callback for the image I have plotted. Then inside the callback I read the `hit.IntersectionPoint`:

```
ax = app.UIAxes;
ih = imagesc(I, 'Parent', ax);
ih.ButtonDownFcn = {@im_ButtonDownFcn, app};
```

_

```
function im_ButtonDownFcn(im, hit, app)
mouse_pos = flip(round(hit.IntersectionPoint(1:2))); %[NaN NaN NaN]
```

On my computer everything works, but on a colleague's computer, it returns NaNs. As far as we can tell, the differences are:

```
Mine (works)       Colleague (NaN)
Win10               MacOS
USB Mouse           Laptop Trackpad
```

Does anyone know if either of these could be a factor in `IntersectionPoint` returning NaNs? Or have another suggestion that we could troubleshoot?

I have read [here](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/406342-app-designer-how-to-get-mouse-position-when-i-click-on-figure) that the `IntersectionPoint` is only available from 2018a onwards. My colleague uses 2017b, but when I tested on 2017b on my computer, the IntersectionPoint still worked.